# Object property not being set but console says otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to set up a stripe verification service using angular. I basically want to call StripeResponse.get() and have it return either the error or the token that Stripe responds with.

My problem is that when I execute this code, if I do `var a = StripeResponse.get();` and then log `a` to the console, I see `null`.

If I add a `console.log(this);` right before `return this.response;`, I see the following:

```
Object {response:null, get: function}
 > get: function() {
 v response: Object
    code: "invalid_number"
    message: "This card number looks invalid"
    param: "number"
    type: "card_error"
```

I don't understand the discrepancy between the "response: null" and "response: Object" in that console log. Below is my code for the service/module.

```
var app = angular.module('StripeVerify', [ ]);

app.service('StripeResponse', function () {
  return {
    response: null,
    get: function () {
      var form = $('form[name="ccForm"]');
      Stripe.createToken(form, $.proxy(function (status, response) {
        if (response.error) {
          return this.response = response.error;
        } else {
          return this.response = response.id;
        }
      }, this));
      return this.response;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you using Chrome Console? If so it shows the reference to this which gets updated during your async task and console also gets updated.. See if `createToken` method returns a promise or something..

Comment: call to Stripe is asynchronous, use a promise to return from `get()`

Comment: @charlietfl I honestly don't know how to go about using a promise to return from get(). I understand the concept of promises but I don't know how to incorporate that into the code.

Comment: @PSL createToken doesn't seem to return a promise. From Stripe's website, createToken "does the work of sending card details to Stripe and waiting for a token or error in response".

Comment: @Mephoros So you should make your `StripeResponse` get method  async. You can use defered object to manage your own promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `createToken` method does not return a promise or does not have a callback mechanism of any kind, You should just utilize angular [$q's Defered API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api) and create a promise pattern for your service.

```
app.service('StripeResponse', ['$q', function ($q) {
  return {
    response: null,
    get: function () {
      var defered = $q.defer(); //Create a deffered object

      var form = $('form[name="ccForm"]');
      Stripe.createToken(form, function (status, response) {
        if (response.error) {
           defered.reject(response.error); //reject the promise

        } else {
            defered.resolve(response.id); //resolve the promise
        }

      });
      return defered.promise;
    }
  }
}]);
```

And while consuming the service you would just do (PseudoCode):

```
  StripeResponseService.get()
  .then(function(id){//Handle Success
  })
  .catch(function(error){//Handle failure
  })
```

Comment: That link to the $q API was much appreciated. This worked perfectly. Thanks! I'm going to go research deferred objects and promises more now, so that I don't have to repeat this kind of question.